# Choose a different folder to override woocommerce templates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

It is possible to choose a different folder to override the WooCommerce templates.

By default the folder is: **theme > woocommerce**.

But I want to change to:  **theme> myShop> templates**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see the [woocommerce_template_path](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/woocommerce.php#L388). Untested, but I think should work.

```
function so_34386333_custom_template_path(){
   return 'myShop/templates/';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_template_path', 'so_34386333_custom_template_path' );
```